# iReport: Using Variables

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm new with [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport) and trying the following:
I want the report to notice in the detail-band when a special field has another value as it has the entry before. 
I think that could be possible if I use a variable but I have no idea how to do that.
Can someone help me out with an example so I can see the right syntax?

I tried to create a parameter `$P{MyField}` and fill it with a statement in the "Print when" like this:

```
($P{MyField}.put("MyField", $F{MyField}) == null  ) ? Boolean.FALSE:Boolean.FALSE
```

I found that in another Report and wanted to use it...

The parameter was set as

```
java.util.Map
```

with default

```
new java.util.HashMap()
```

I think I'm totally wrong... so if someone could help?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a rectangle, for example, with a special style, and set the condition at the porperty "print when expression", so the special rectangle would only be printed when it really should be.