# fetching records from database based on variable number of inputs from from

Tags: java

I have a form with 8 fields and based on the values entered in them I have have to fetch the records from the DataBase. Now the problem is out of the 8 fields the user may fill any number of fields and that too in any order for example the user may fill fields 1,4 and 6 or he may fill 1 and 7 or he may fill all of them (of course he has to fill at least one field)... Now how will I write a query which will work for any number and order of input parameters? and also because this query will be used in reporting(iReport) I am not allowed to write any code with it , it has to be a SQL query. Any ideas

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean there are 8 fields and the user may fetch some fields or all fields ? also did you tried anything ?

Comment: i am developing a web appication. i have a form containing 8 fields , onClicking search button , application should fetch records from database based on the above mentioned criteria

Comment: Can you see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138864/ireport-using-variables

Comment: it's not that what i am looking for... :(

Comment: You can use [dynamic SQL](http://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2009/01/09/creating-dynamic-where-clauses-with-sql.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

there are a number of ways to do this. I have a blog post about doing something like this in a Microsoft SQL (T-SQL) stored procedure at http://code.scottshipp.com/2013/03/29/tutorial-stored-procedures-with-truly-optional-parameters/ but it is likely that you will want to do something more complex and/or you are not using MS SQL Server. You may have to write the query fragments yourself. My suggestion is to do something like the following:

1. Once the form is submitted, loop through the various fields in the form, and check if their values are empty or not.
2. For those that are not empty, add a string containing an appropriate corresponding query fragment to some collections object, like an ArrayList. Do not include "AND" or "OR" directly in this string. If you need to keep track of whether this query fragment gets "AND"ed or "OR"ed with other query fragments, track that in a separate collections object. The "query fragment" I'm talking about is what would show up in the "where **__**" portion of your SQL query. For instance, say the search was for someone's last name. The query fragment you add is a string that says "lastName='" + lastNameField.value() + "'".
3. Once you have iterated through all the various fields in the form and have a final collections object full of query fragments, construct the final SQL statement from it. Iterate through your collections object (ArrayList in this example) and connect each one with the appropriate "AND" or "OR". Say your ArrayList has the three fragments "firstName='Joe'", "middleName='Q.'", "lastName='Public'". Use a StringBuilder to keep adding these fragments together into a final where clause: "firstName='Joe' AND middleName='Q.' AND lastName='Public'"...you may want to change these to a "LIKE" style query with wildcard characters.
4. You now have everything you need to create the final select statement. Issue it to the database and retrieve your results!